# Is any license needed, to build an open-source forum / community?

Tags: licensing, open-source-definition, license-file, community

Is any license / paperwork need to build an open-source forum / community like stack overflow or like others Linux community site?

If needed then from where i can get license for my forum / community, at low cost or free.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. It fills my head with ideas, but I am not exactly sure what they are. I can think of several answers, but all to different questions. Which question are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

> Is any license / paperwork need to build an open-source forum / community like stack overflow or like others Linux community site ?

Whether your project is code-oriented or community-oriented, you will need to decide on a licence.  Otherwise, the community won't know what rights it has to use your content, and people won't know what they're giving away when they contribute.  Both of these are a big discouragement to the formation of any kind of community.  Picking a licence, whether for content or for code, puts your answers to this front and centre, where people can see them.

> If needed then from where i can get license for my forum / community, at low cost or free.

If you're looking to pick a free licence, either for code or content, there are a number of sites that can help you.  We can also help, but you will need to be **much** more specific and tell us what kind of resource you're looking to license (code repository?  community forum?  clipart collection?), what sort of rights you want to give your users, and what you want to retain.

There are no financial costs incurred by the act of using any kind of free licence.

Comment: hey @MadHatter there is  community forum where users have their account, profile info,can posts,view,chat,message,a donation box,may have sponsor user for direct posting their ads on this platform.and users data can be used by / sold to  third party for business analytical purpose or site enhancement , For now that's it.

Comment: can you provide me license copy @MadHatter ?,Your mail address....?

Comment: @MDIRFANALI no, that's not how this works.  I suggest you write a new question, referring to this one, where you list in yet more detail the points you provide above, and ask about a licence, so the community  can make recommendations.  I note that you've said what sort of privacy policy you might need (re users' data), even though that's not something we can help with, but you've still said nothing about the licensing of **content**.  If I come to your forum, and someone's posted an image / piece of code / poem that I want to reuse, what rights do you want me to have as a user?

Comment: To avoid your next question gathering downvotes, or worse, getting closed. I strongly recommend you read our guide [How do I ask for a license recommendation?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/how-do-i-ask-for-a-license-recommendation) first.